# How to completely uninstall youtube-dl from windows?

Tags: youtube-dl

I am not comfortable using this and would like to uninstall it completely from my system.

**EDIT:**

I had downloaded an extension file through their website which had the python support inbuilt in it and I cannot find it in the add/remove feature.

Comment: I tried locating youtube-dl at the add/remove program features but I could not locate it.@DavidPostill

Comment: The file is called `youtube-dl.exe`, you can try searching for that file in File Explorer. https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `youtube-dl` in command prompt, it means that `youtube-dl.exe` is in your `PATH`, making it easy to locate.

To find where it is, just open a command prompt window and type:

```
where youtube-dl
```

It will output the file path where `youtube-dl.exe` is hiding. For me, this was the output:

```
C:\Users\pigeonburger\Desktop\Dev\youtube-dl.exe
```

Now to remove the file, run this:

```
del C:\Users\pigeonburger\Desktop\Dev\youtube-dl.exe
```

(replacing the `C:\Users\pigeonburger\Desktop\Dev\youtube-dl.exe` with your own file path, of course)

`youtube-dl` is now uninstalled!

Answer (score 0):

- Check the log file of the program to see where it copied files and where it modified the registry. The uninstall information is usually stored into a file called unins000.dat, that can be found in the installation folder.
- Uninstall by standard means (Add/Remove or Programs & Features)
- Delete the installation destination
- Remove the remaining registry entries and/or remaining files copied in other locations.

Comment: I could not locate youtube-dl through add/remove program features.

Comment: Then just look at task manager to see if it's running and if it is end task it, then delete the installation folder.